# Unbased_unsized_literal vs unsized literal constants

Tags: system-verilog

I have been reading the SystemVerilog (SV) spec, but can't figure out if the following code will get the same result in SV:

```
logic [WIDTH-1:0] signal;
assign signal = '0;
```

and

```
logic [WIDTH-1:0] signal;
assign signal = 'd0;
```

I believe the following would be different:

```
logic [WIDTH-1:0] signal;
assign signal = '1;
```

and

```
logic [WIDTH-1:0] signal;
assign signal = 'd1;
```

Where the top one would assign '1' to all bits in `signal`.

Is there something I should be looking out for when using `'d0`?
Are there lint or sizing restrictions with this coding format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literals `'0 '1, 'x , 'z` are *fill* literals. They expand to the width based on the context they appear in. Outside of any other context, they are 1-bit wide.

There is a difference in some expressions

```
bit [63:0] signals;
assign signal = {1'b1,'d0}; // illegal, but some tools produce 64'h 00000000100000000
assign signal = {1'b1, '0}; // '0 is 1'b0 in a concatenation        00000000000000002
```

The LRM forbids unsized literal constants inside a concatenation, but some tools let it slip through.

My suggestion is using only fill literals or a sized based literals when they are part of a larger expression or port connection. An unsized literal is OK as the sole RHS of an assignment or actual argument to a task or function.

Comment: If I wanted to assign signal reset value to 0xF, would you recommend ```assign signal = 'hF``` or ```assign signal = {(WIDTH-4){1'b0}, 4'hF}```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `signal` will have the same value with `'0` and with `'d0` for simulation.  Both set all bits of `signal` to 0, regardless of the value of `WIDTH` (even large values like 128).  Since `'0` is simpler, prefer that.

If `WIDTH` is 1, then `'1` and `'d1` will result in the same value for `signal`.

If `WIDTH` is greater than 1, they will be different: `'d1` sets `signal[0]` to 1 and all other bits to 0.  `'1` sets all bits to 1.